# Android WebView, how to code for device back button?

Tags: java, android, webview

I am developing one app, which has two Activities. The Second Activity has a button which is using web view. When I am clicking on that button I am going on web view but when I am pressing on Back button of device then the app is going to the First Activity, but I want to go again on Second Activity. How can I implement this I tried many techniques. Here is my code.

```
public void onBackPressed (){

if (webview.isFocused() && webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack();       
}
else {
        super.onBackPressed();

}
}
```

Comment: you are using finish method..,thats why it is coming on first..

Comment: us eintent on button click..,so u will be on your activity...

Comment: Sorry I didn't remove that , but still problem is same.

Comment: I tried intent also but, I am getting following error   06-29 23:11:17.796: I/Choreographer(691): Skipped 647 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: delete `super.onBackPressed();`

Comment: Let me try it @Spring

Comment: It will not work because the compiler will not go in else part.

Comment: is that `WebView` is inside your  Second Activity?

Comment: Yes webview is in SecondActivity @ Spring

Comment: You are already in SecondActivity then why you want to go to the same screen after clicking the back button?

Comment: No, when webview is opening, and I am clicking on back button, then I am going on First Activity. But I want to go again in SecondActivity